Reliable battery power converter for ESP32
I have seen similar (but just similar) questions here, so I decided to ask anyway.
What is a buck-boost module, preferrably from Aliexpress, that I can use to power an ESP32 with 3.3 V from a 3.7 V lithium battery, with a 500 mA budget?
Despite an LDO like the AMS1117-3.3 going all the way to 1 A, it wouldn't make the cut because the lithium batteries can go down to 3.2 V.
I found a module with the HX4002B charge pump chip, but it goes just up to 150 mA.

You don't need a buck-boost.  You need a buck that switches to pass mode when the input voltage is too low.
The ESP32 doesn't need exactly 3.3V.  It needs at most 3.6 V (maximum allowed, do not exceed) but works properly down to about 2.5V.
All you really need is a buck converter that drops the voltage to 3.3V.
I've used some LM3671 modules for this very purpose.  I've had a couple of ESP32 modules running from solar charged battery banks for several years now.  They work just fine with the LM3671 modules regulating the voltage from the lithium cell.

That's one answer, thank you
